# Mongodb geosphere and haystack indexes rejecting valid line strings

Tags: c++, mongodb, geojson

I have attempted to insert the following geojsonlint data with each of the three geographic indexes.  The only one which accepts the data is the 2d index.

The haystack index produces the following error:

```
insertDocument :: caused by :: 16776 geo field is not a number
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "geometry.coordinates" : "geoHaystack",
        "properties.asset_type" : 1
    },
    "name" : "geometry.coordinates_geoHaystack_properties.asset_type_1",
    "ns" : "smallcell.poles",
    "bucketSize" : 1
}
```

The 2dsphere produces the following error:

```
insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?

{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "geometry.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "name" : "geometry.coordinates_2dsphere",
    "ns" : "smallcell.poles",
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
{
    type : "Feature",
    geometry : {
        type : "LineString",
        coordinates : [[-118.6058, 34.17195], [-118.60589, 34.17195], [-118.606057, 34.171953], [-118.606096, 34.171954], [-118.60647, 34.17196], [-118.60702, 34.17196], [-118.60713, 34.17196], [-118.6076, 34.17195], [-118.6077, 34.17195], [-118.60779, 34.171949], [-118.6088, 34.17194], [-118.609203, 34.17194], [-118.60932, 34.17194], [-118.60964, 34.17195], [-118.6102, 34.17198], [-118.6104, 34.172], [-118.610704, 34.172031], [-118.61089, 34.17205], [-118.61115, 34.17207], [-118.61135, 34.17207], [-118.61175, 34.17204], [-118.61215, 34.17199], [-118.61265, 34.17196], [-118.61366, 34.17196], [-118.61455, 34.17196], [-118.61678, 34.17196], [-118.61819, 34.17197], [-118.61896, 34.17196], [-118.61971, 34.17195], [-118.620452, 34.17195], [-118.62115, 34.17195], [-118.62153, 34.17195], [-118.62287, 34.17196], [-118.62333, 34.17197], [-118.6238, 34.17197], [-118.62543, 34.17196], [-118.62731, 34.17194], [-118.628244, 34.17194], [-118.62957, 34.17194], [-118.63206, 34.17192]]
    },
    properties : {
        id : 0.0,
        asset_type : "FBR",
        carrier : "AT&T",
        type : "ON_ROAD",
        cbsa : "31100",
        lata : "730",
        zip : null,
        state : null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index is on the wrong field.
The indexed field should be `geometry`, not `geometry.coordinates`.

Example code:

```
var lineString = {
    type : "Feature",
    geometry : {
        type : "LineString",
        coordinates : [[-118.6058, 34.17195], [-118.60589, 34.17195], [-118.606057, 34.171953], [-118.606096, 34.171954], [-118.60647, 34.17196], [-118.60702, 34.17196], [-118.60713, 34.17196], [-118.6076, 34.17195], [-118.6077, 34.17195], [-118.60779, 34.171949], [-118.6088, 34.17194], [-118.609203, 34.17194], [-118.60932, 34.17194], [-118.60964, 34.17195], [-118.6102, 34.17198], [-118.6104, 34.172], [-118.610704, 34.172031], [-118.61089, 34.17205], [-118.61115, 34.17207], [-118.61135, 34.17207], [-118.61175, 34.17204], [-118.61215, 34.17199], [-118.61265, 34.17196], [-118.61366, 34.17196], [-118.61455, 34.17196], [-118.61678, 34.17196], [-118.61819, 34.17197], [-118.61896, 34.17196], [-118.61971, 34.17195], [-118.620452, 34.17195], [-118.62115, 34.17195], [-118.62153, 34.17195], [-118.62287, 34.17196], [-118.62333, 34.17197], [-118.6238, 34.17197], [-118.62543, 34.17196], [-118.62731, 34.17194], [-118.628244, 34.17194], [-118.62957, 34.17194], [-118.63206, 34.17192]]
    },
    properties : {
        id : 0.0,
        asset_type : "FBR",
        carrier : "AT&T",
        type : "ON_ROAD",
        cbsa : "31100",
        lata : "730",
        zip : null,
        state : null
    }
};
db.testLS.remove({});
db.testLS.ensureIndex( { geometry : "2dsphere" } );
db.testLS.insert( lineString );

// example query using a point
db.testLS.find( { geometry : {
    $near : {
        $geometry : {
            type : "Point",
            coordinates : [ 110, 30 ]
        }
    }
} } );
// returns the lineString object.
```